# Why throwing an error inside a function called from another function breaks the angular app

Tags: angular, typescript, exception, error-handling

I have a function in my component which calls an API like that

```
async func1() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    try {
      await this.api.callToApi();
    } catch (ex) {
      console.log(ex);
    }
  }
```

inside the API the function `callToApi` is defined as follows

```
try {
      // make a call to API and return result
    } catch (ex) {
      this.handleError(ex);
    }
```

and then the function `handleError`

```
async handleError(er: any) {
      throw er;
  }
```

My problem is that when I make a call to the api from `func1` and then there is some error, then the function `handleError` throws the error and the `func1` doesn't catch it and thus, the whole app breaks. From my understanding, after throwing error in `handleError` then this error should be propagated to the called, in this case `func1`. Why is this not the case?

Please note that I have only shown related code and that I can make it work as needed by removing the whole `try-catch` block from the `callToApi` function and don't use `handleError` at all but that is not the point.

Edit1: To clarify what I want here is that I want the catch block from `func1` to be **activated**.

It would look something like this:

```
func1()
--> callToApi()
----> handleError() (on error propagate it back to func1)
```

Edit2: To clear confustion, the reason I have `handleError` at all is because there may be multiple errors which I need to handle inside it. However, there is 1 specific error which must be propagated back to func1 to handle it there. Is this going to be possible at all?

Comment: I feel like you're trying to solve a problem here, but not telling us what the problem is. It just looks like your solution didn't worked. So what kind of error are you trying to catch here, why do you need to catch, and why is your source code so unstable that you have two nested catches?

Comment: I want the catch block from `func1` to be activated. The first function `func1` has a catch block. It calls the API through `callToApi`, which on error calls `handleError` which simply throws it. I want after `handleError` throws its error, then this error to be caught by `func1`

Comment: oh, I can reproduce your problem. I see what you mean.

Comment: The error is indeed shown but it is not handled by the `func1` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `handleError` is declared with `async` which means that when you throw error inside the function, it actually returns a rejected promise. The `func1` will catch it if you remove the `async` statement:

```
    handleError(er) {
        throw er;
    }
```

If you really need that function to be asynchronous then you can modify `callToApi` to be something like this:

```
        try {
            // make a call to API and return result
        } catch (ex) {
            await this.handleError(ex);
        }
```

or this:

```
        try {
            // make a call to API and return result
        } catch (ex) {
            return this.handleError(ex);
        }
```

Comment: It did fix the problem. It looks like every time one has an issue with Async Js, await should be the first thing to try!